# How do I collect a list of rss feeds?

Tags: web-development, development-process, project, rss

I am developing a rss reader where users search and follow blogs. But, how will I collect and store the feeds of thousands of blogs?

Manual process of adding individual feeds is painful. Is there an easier way to add or import site feeds?

Comment: You could look at open source solutions like the Sage RSS reader plugin for Firefox: http://sagerss.com/  Sage has an OPML import for feed definitions.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to automate RSS feed discovery, or a way to import feed definitions?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Exactly! How could I do it?

Comment: @user1117972: You mean you want both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blekko has an API that provides the RSS link and other relevant details for any site.

Example : http://blekko.com/ws/cnn+/json

Change cnn to any other topic or site name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't brute force it.  Include a feature (off by default or with a prompt) to send RSS feeds they add your way.  The same central server that your RSS reader would contact to get a corrected list of feeds (such as when feed X changes its URL) can have an interface to share new feeds.

Just be sure to have your system include some handshake value as well to ward off spam, and be sure not to test the RSS feeds automatically so you're not liable to help someone's DDOS attack.